# CREATE combined with FOREACH in CYPHER gives unexpected results

Tags: foreach, neo4j, cypher

I have a graph in which versioning information is stored as [:ADD] or [:REMOVE] relations between nodes. I want to replace those rels by another model, based on  [:UPDATE] rels with property type and timestamp.

Currently

```
MATCH (n:tocversion)-[r:ADD]->(m) 
RETURN n.version,id(m)
```

returns this (as expected)

```
n.version,id(m)
1,13
1,14
2,15
2,16
3,17
3,18
3,19
3,20
4,21
4,22
```

Now I thought I could collect the versions and m's and use them as a basis to create rels in the new model.  Like this.

```
MATCH (n:tocversion)-[r:ADD]->(m),(t:toc) 
WITH t,COLLECT(n.version) AS versions, COLLECT(m) AS ms
FOREACH(i IN versions |
    FOREACH(m1 IN [ms[i]]|
        CREATE (t)-[r1:UPDATE {type:"ADD", version:versions[i]}]->(m1)))
```

However, the rels are created in a way I don't understand, because

```
MATCH (t:toc)-[r:`UPDATE`]->(b) RETURN r.version,r.type,id(b)
```

returns

```
r.version,r.type,id(b)
  1,      ADD,      14
  1,      ADD,      14
  2,      ADD,      15
  2,      ADD,      15
  2,      ADD,      16
  2,      ADD,      16
  2,      ADD,      16
  2,      ADD,      16
  3,      ADD,      17
  3,      ADD,      17
```

instead of the expected

```
r.version,r.type,id(b)
  1,      ADD,      13
  1,      ADD,      14
  2,      ADD,      15
  2,      ADD,      16
  3,      ADD,      17
  3,      ADD,      18
  3,      ADD,      19
  3,      ADD,      20
  4,      ADD,      21
  4,      ADD,      22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. Had to use RANGE

```
match (n:tocversion)-[r:ADD]->(m),(t:toc) 
with t,collect(n.version) as versions, collect(m) as ms
foreach(i in RANGE(0, LENGTH(versions)-1) |
    foreach(m1 in [ms[i]]|
        create (t)-[r1:UPDATE5 {type:"ADD", version:versions[i]}]->(m1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely because of this:

```
FOREACH(i IN versions |
FOREACH(m1 IN [ms[i]] |
```

Your "i" is going to be: 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, as expected.

But if you're using those as indices into the ms[] collection (which is 0-based), you're going to be looking at ms[] = {13, 14, 15, 16, 17, .. , 22}, and so ms[1] will always be 14, ms[2] will always be 15, ms[3] will always be 16, and ms[4] will always be 17.

Your "foreach" loops need to be rethought as "i" shouldn't be used as a lookup into "ms".

In fact I'm also not certain "i" should be used as an index into "versions" which you do in your CREATE statement as you'll likely have a similar issue as above (e.g. versions[3] will always be 2).